# Totient function trick?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

I would like to search for primes of the form $$\varphi(n)^n+n$$ where $\ \varphi(n)\ $ denotes the totient function.

The problem is that neither pfgw nor factordb seems to support the totient-function.

> Is there some trick allowing to determine the totient-function with some other functions that are supported by pfgw ?

With PARI/GP, I calculated the positive integers $n$, such that the above expression is prime. These are $\ 1,2,3,187\ $ and no other below $\ 3\ 000\ $

Comment: Clearly $n$ must be square free, hence is the product of distinct primes.  But if $n=\prod p_i$  then $\varphi(n)=\prod (p_i-1)$.

Comment: @lulu Nice observation! Unfortunately, pfgw does not support this either.

Comment: Well, your numbers are so small that you can code that explicitly. Granted, this gets a lot harder if it is difficult to factor $n$ but for small $n$ this is not difficult.

Comment: @lulu pfgw and factordb would however be much faster in primality testing. That is the reason, I ask.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem puts restrictions up. As was once pointed outbon a Mathphile question.

Comment: For what it's worth, Wolfram Alpha can check up to 200: `Select[Range[200], PrimeQ[EulerPhi[#]^# + #] &]`

Comment: 1,2,4,6,8,10,12,16,18,20,22,24,28,30,32,36,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,58,60,64,66,68,70,72,78,80,82,84,88,90,92,96,104,110,116,120,128,132,144,164,168,170,176,184,188,200,204,212,216,224,230,236,242,272,284,288,290,300,304,320,324,332,340,342,344,356,360,364,368,374,384,404,410,424,428,440,444,450,452,464,468,470,480,500,504,506,510,512,524,528,530,544,548,552,560,564,578,584,590,594,596,624,636,638,644,656,664,668,680,684,692,702,704,710,716,720,752,764,780,782,784,788,792,800,804,824,830,832,840,846,848,864,884,888,890,902,904,908,920,930,932,944,956,960,968,972,986,1000, kicked out via Fermat.

Comment: `for(n=1,1000,forprime(p=1,1000,y=p^2-p;if(n%y==p-1 && eulerphi(n)%p!=0,print1(n",");break(1))))`  for deeper results

Comment: I passed $n=12\ 500$ without finding another prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The totient function of an integer $n$ with prime factorisation $\prod \limits_{k=1}^r p_k^{\alpha_k}$ is given by $\varphi(n) = \prod \limits_{k=1}^r p_k^{\alpha_k-1}(p_k-1)$. This allows you to determine the totient based off a prime factorisation, and furthermore also tells you that $n$ cannot have a square factor since if $p^2$ divides $n$ then $p$ divides $\varphi(n)$, and so we now have $\varphi(n) = \prod \limits_{k=1}^r (p_k-1)$ where $n$ is a product of distinct primes.

Comment: As far as I know, this approach cannot be applied in pfgw.

Comment: why the obsession with PFGW ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Seems you don't read the comments, when it comes to huge numbers, pfgw is far superior in primality testing compared to pari/gp. And I am particular interested in huge primes. I do not know what you want to show with Fermat's little theorem in context with this question, but lulu's comment ($n$ must be squarefree) and that $n$ must obviously be odd (expcept $n=2$) is already quite restricting.

Comment: n=4 mod 20, forces phi(n) to be 0 mod 5 or bust. 6 mod 20 forces not 2 or 3 mod 5 phi(n). etc.